# calculate timestamp interval average

Tags: mysql, timestamp, using, average, intervals

Appreciate your help on this.

I am trying to calculate averages based on user selected intervals, which are multiples of 5. So, a user can select 10 minutes interval at one time while running the query and can select any other intervals like 15, 20,...upto through 60 minutes interval on other runs.

The input file has column for 5 minutes interval average.

Suppose this is the input file, myTable

```
timestamp                     units     
4/25/2012 12:00:00 AM          50        
4/25/2012 12:00:05 AM          45
4/25/2012 12:00:10 AM          78
4/25/2012 12:00:15 AM          56
.                              .
.(in 5 mins increment)         .
.                              .
4/25/2012 12:00:50 AM          45
4/25/2012 12:00:55 AM          60
4/25/2012 1:00:00 AM           40
4/25/2012 1:00:05 AM           50
.                              . 
.                              .            
.                              .
4/25/2012 11:55:00 PM          39
.
.
```

Let's say we chose 10 minutes interval. The output should be like

```
timestamp          Average
4/25/2012 0:00     50
4/25/2012 0:10     60.5   -- which is (45+ 78)/2
.
.
.
4/25/2012 0:50    .
4/25/2012 1:00    50 -- which is (60+40)/2
4/25/2012 1:10
```

Any suggestions. thanks!

I found a way to group the minutes by using when then, and it seems to be working for all cases except when the next time stamp is for the next hour. so, in input the table above, for 4/25/2012 12:00:55 AM          60
    4/25/2012 1:00:00 AM           40
I am getting two rows with the values above instead of one average. Any idea how I could fix this boundary case when the time changes to the next hour.

Thanks

Comment: It's very hard to understand what the question here is, please try to rephrase it and give more examples.